# large numbers - my horse in name the biggest number contest

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I read Scott Aaronson's essay Who can name the biggest number and I wonder about a following large number.

Take a hundred and apply a factorial function take the result and apply a factorial function and repeat this process until you have applied the factorial function 100 factorial times.

I don't claim that it is the largest number in the history of human thought... :-D but I do wonder how large it is and how it compares to other big numbers.

Based on the comments and answers I figure that my number will be something like 10^(10^(10... where there is 100! 10s. Which is not that big compared to certain elements of certain uncomputable sequences, but whatever.

Comment: Infinity is larger (by definition.) than any number you could write.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham's_number.

Answer (score 2):

According to Stirling, $n! = \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}(1 + o(1))$. I'd try to use it to estimate the result. It would be pretty big, but there's infinite number of natural numbers.

Comment: Great! This means it's approximately the same as $N_{100}$ where $N_0 = 100$ and $N_{i+1} = N_i ^ {N_i}$. This gives me the feeling that it's _nowhere_ as big as $g_{64}$, but I'm not sure at all. __EDIT__: Missed the $\sqrt{n}$ part.. don't take me seriously

Comment: @Guido, I'd say it's less than $N_{100}$, because $n! < n^n$.

Comment: I understand that the Stirling approximation is more and more valid as n grows. Is that correct?

Comment: @Adam, yes, it can be put as $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n!}{n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}} = 1$

Comment: Try TREE($3$): https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2006-March/010290.html

Comment: @Guido:  for a purpose like this, the $\sqrt n$ doesn't matter at all.  We have $\log 100!\approx 100(\log 100-1)+\frac 12\log(200\pi)\approx 360.517+3.222$ so it only changes $\log 100!$ by $1\%$.  Yes, that is a factor of $25$ in $100!$, but out of $10^{157}$ do we care?